# Using the Windows Credential Manager for a SQL connection in a .NET 5 console app

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

We need to connect to different SQL servers with different credentials in different domains and we don't want to store the passwords as plain text in a config file. That's why we would like to use the Windows Credential Manager (Windows Password Vault) for the authentication while establishing a connection to a (remote) Microsoft SQL Server in a .NET 5 console application.

Does anybody know if this is possible and if so, how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CredentialManagement:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/1.0.2?_src=template

Then utilize it like so:

```
string username;
string password;
using (var credential = new Credential())
{
    credential.Target = "networkaddress";
    username = credential.Username;
    password = credential.Password;
}
```